# Function to get sum of array of numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Javascript

I'm getting `00.10.10.20.20.050.050.05` as my output.
However, I want the sum which should be `.75`

```
var array = ['0.1','0.1','0.2','0.2','0.05','0.05','0.05']
var sum = 0;
function sumArray() {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    for (i=0; i < array.length ; i++) {
      sum +=array[i];
    }

}
sumArray();
alert(sum);
```

Comment: A string is not a number...

Answer (score 2):

Actually you are concatenating strings (your array has strings on it). Just parse your strings:

```
var array = ['0.1','0.1','0.2','0.2','0.05','0.05','0.05']
var sum = 0;
function sumArray() {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    for (i=0; i < array.length ; i++) {
      sum += parseFloat(array[i]);
    }

}
sumArray();
alert(sum);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let array = ['0.1','0.1','0.2','0.2','0.05','0.05','0.05'];
let sum = array.reduce((a, b) => parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b));
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: You're not using the same array as the question.